# Get ObservableCollection<Object> as result of RIA Services under WPF Client to RIA Services

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf-ria-services

Is there some way to get `ObservableCollection<Object>` as result of RIA Services method under *WPF Client to RIA Services*?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, You can map your Ria Service Result as IEnumerable and after, init new ObservableCollection(riaOperationContractResult) when service response.
This is an example:

```
MyService myService = new MyService();
myService.OnOperationContractExecuted += new EventHandler(OnOperationContractExecuted);
myService.BeginOperationContract(...);

...

private void OnOperationContractExecuted(object sender, OperationContractEventArgs e) {
    IEnumerable<MyServiceObj> objs = (IEnumerable<MyServiceObj>e.Result);
    ObservableCollection<MyServiceObj> obsObjs = new ObservableCollection<MyServiceObj>(objs);
}

...
```

Comment: Is MyService a DomainService?

Comment: No, MyService is the Proxy used to communicate with the service.